# I want to show Modal box when I click a button in VUE js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have created the code using bootstrap and VUE js. When I click the button the popup window not showing. I have used VUE js components. I want my output to look like https://prnt.sc/pkhrff but now I am clicking the button nothing happened. My code is here to review!

HTML:

```
<div class="register-wrap"  id="register-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Online registration for Vue Training</h2>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                <div class="registerbtn">
                    <h3>Register Now Today!</h3>
                    <modalregister v-if="showModal" @close= "showModal = false">
                        <p>Enter your text here</p>
                    </modalregister>
                    <input type="submit" @click = "showModal = true" class="form-control" value="Register Now">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

VUE js:

```
Vue.component('modalregister',{
    template:`
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <slot></slot>
                    </div>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" @click="$emit('close')"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
});

new Vue({
    el:'#register-wrap',

    data: {
        showModal: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at using http://bootstrap-vue.js.org instead of native bootstrap. Makes it a lot easier to use bootstrap components inside of Vue

Comment: Yet not tried, I will try now.

Comment: Please share a fiddle/sandbox where issue can be reproduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can look up page source to see if component is rendered.
2. Your modal is hidden by default. You can change following:

   ```
       <div class="modal fade">
   ```

   To

   ```
       <div class="modal fade show">
   ```
3. Add component to Vue instance

   `const modalregister =  Vue.component('modalregister',{...`

   `new Vue({
       el:'#register-wrap',
       components: { modalregister },
       ...`

Comment: I changed to class="modal fade show", but still not working. I saw it via Vue instance https://prnt.sc/pkif17
Is there any problem with the bootstrap show or hide problem??

Comment: Did you looked up rendered html after clicking at *Register Now* button? Check if there are modal elements.
Maybe you need to register component in Vue instance **modalregister**.

Comment: No. How to check modal elements?

Comment: With browser build-in DOM Inspector.

Comment: This is for button element: https://prnt.sc/pkis02
This is for modal element: https://prnt.sc/pkish1
When I click modal element CSS shows display: none
How to rectify that

Comment: Element over the button is your modal div. Click on it and in Rules tab check why is it not visible. Your vue script works correctly, you only need to fix styles.